# AUCTeX: switch to LuaLaTex from PDFLaTeX

Tags: luatex, auctex

I just installed the Lucida Bright OpenType fonts, and it turns out they don't work with pdfLaTeX, which is what AUCTeX was configured to run with the "LaTeX" command when I first installed it.  Now I want to run LuaLaTeX instead so that I can use the Lucida Bright fonts.  How do I make that change?

Comment: I have “'(TeX-engine (quote luatex))” in my `.emacs`.  Not sure that’s the best way to do it, but it works.

Comment: @Thérèse That gives me:  "Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-engine"

Comment: That sounds like a message I used to get several versions of auctex ago.  Which version do you have?

Comment: @Ruby - Try to set a file local variable at the end of your file: `%%% Local Variables:  \n %%% TeX-engine: luatex  \n %%% End: ` (Replace `\n` with `RET`)

Comment: @ArashEsbati Setting that local variable at the end of the file didn't help.  AUCTeX still ran PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @Thérèse How do I find out which version of AUCTeX I have?  I'm sure that what I have must be very old, since I'm still using emacs 22.  I tried updating to emacs 24 about a year ago, but switching to 24 was more involved than with previous emacs updates, and it didn't seem worth the work.

Comment: @Ruby - Did you also hit `C-c C-n` after setting it?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I hadn't tried that.  But now I have, and still no change.

Comment: @Ruby - I'm afraid then that your AUCTeX is too old; you can find your version `C-h v AUCTeX-version RET`.  Updating your `emacs` would be a good idea.  You have access to many packages incl. `AUCTeX` via `ELPA`.

Comment: I have 11.85.  I'm guessing that's very very old.

Comment: One way to find the version is to read the opening lines of `auctex.el`.  But if you want to work with `luatex`, you should use the most recent version of emacs, as well as an up-to-date auctex, because support for unicode has improved dramatically in emacs.

Comment: You should have 11.89.

Comment: Do you want to make `luatex` the default for all `.tex` files (as my suggestion would do), or only have it as an option in auctex’s command menu (I think it will be there with no effort on your part in recent versions of emacs/auctex), or set it as the default for particular files (as ArashEsbati’s suggestion would do)?

Comment: @Thérèse Well, I'm not yet at all familiar with luatex.  I just want to use it so that I can use the Lucida fonts.  Do I need to have emacs 24?  Am I right in remembering that updating to emacs 24 was very different from updating before then?

Comment: I don’t remember emacs 23 very clearly, but if you’re going to upgrade, you may as well upgrade to something current.  Installing emacs 24, and even an experimental version of emacs 25, was easy on my system (Debian GNU/Linux), but other systems may have a more complicated procedure.

Comment: If anyone else is still reading this, the correct command to put in `.emacs` that worked for me was `(setq TeX-engine (quote luatex))`.