# Emacs + auctex freezes when compiling with lualatex

Tags: luatex, emacs, auctex

Trying to compile the following using C-c C-c in emacs + auctex freezes emacs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
asdf
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: lualatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Is there a mistake in my local variables? I was following following advice: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285012/auctex-switch-to-lualatex-from-pdflatex#comment688041_285012). My emacs and my auctex should be up to date.

emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.1.1

auctex version: 11.90.0

Comment: It is `%%% TeX-engine: luatex`.  (You are naming the engine with the variable, not the format.)

Comment: @jon I see, that was the mistake. Can you formulate your comment as a reply? Then I can mark my question as answered.

Comment: When you open the file with `lualatex` as engine, you should be warned that it isn't a safe value, because it isn't valid.  Anyway, I fixed the freeze in AUCTeX, now you should get a meaningful error instead of freezing Emacs when an invalid engine is set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the "Local Variables" settings, you may declare the 'engine' that Emacs will call. Usually your choice will be one of `default`¹ `luatex`, or `xetex`. The `mode`, conversely will name the format you are using (e.g., `context`, `latex`, or `tex`).

Thus, for a LaTeX document that requires the LuaTeX engine, which you'd normally call with the command `lualatex` in a terminal, you could use the following:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex 
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t 
%%% End:
```

When Emacs opens a new `.tex` file in the buffer, it queries what my master file will be (default is `t`, which means the current new file/buffer will be its own master) and presumes the `latex` format. Now, if I want to specify the engine, I can add the `TeX-engine` line. You can also temporarily select the engine (for the remainder of the time Emacs is visiting the file with `M-x TeX-engine-set RET <default|luatex|xetex> RET`.

Another thing you can do for a whole directory is create a file called `.dir-locals-el` that contains the line:

```lisp
((latex-mode    
  (TeX-engine . luatex)))
```

This sets the default engine for the directory to `luatex`.  If you want to name the master file, you could additionally do:

```lisp
((latex-mode
  (TeX-engine . luatex)   
  (TeX-master . "mainfile"))) ;; now mainfile.tex is the master file for the directory
```

¹ My `.emacs` has `pdfTeX` as my default engine, which is surely what the default default is; but this could be changed.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to cause AUCTeX to generate the line `%%% TeX-engine: luatex` automatically, the same way it does the other file-variable directives?

Comment: @EvanAad -- Wouldn't you rather change the default engine? (E.g., in `.emacs`: `(setq-default TeX-engine 'luatex)` and, probably, `(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)`.)

Comment: Thanks. What does `TeX-PDF-mode` do?

Comment: @EvanAad -- It sets whether you want output to be PDF or not by default. (Note: it is also possible to add a command so your `Local Variables` includes the line you want. I'm not sure which approach is more suitable in your case.)